# Come si dice in italiano data science?

Tags: translation

La *data science* è un campo di studio multidisciplinare che si è definito negli ultimi anni; non ho trovato una espressione equivalente in italiano.
Non so nemmeno come si debba tradurre *data scientist*. Come si dice in italiano?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Io utilizzerei per *data science* il termine **analisi dati** volto ad indicare l'operazione eseguita da una persona che è responsabile dell'analisi dei risultati o misurazioni provenienti da un sistema informatico o in generale da un apparato che produce una storia dell'andamento temporale delle principali grandezze che lo caratterizzano.

Ti può essere utile questo articolo [«Coraggio e avventura, così sono diventato il “data scientist” di Tesla»](http://www.linkiesta.it/it/article/2015/07/21/coraggio-e-avventura-cosi-sono-diventato-il-data-scientist-di-tesla/26765/) in cui viene spiegato il ruolo di *data scientist* o **analista dati**:

> Lavoro all’interno della Product Excellence e il gruppo che guido è
>   responsabile dell’analisi dei dati che provengono dalle nostre auto al
>   fine di capirne l’utilizzo, identificare problemi prima che si
>   manifestino sul campo e provvedere ai dati per il design dei
>   componenti di nuovi modelli.

Comment: Nel complesso condivido la risposta, ma questa parte mi sembra un po' circolare: “il termine analisi dati volto ad indicare l'operazione eseguita da una persona che è responsabile dell'analisi dei dati”; cioè, l'analisi dati è ciò che fa chi fa l'analisi dati? :-) Lo so che il seguito della frase chiarisce meglio, ma forse si poteva formulare un po' diversamente.

Comment: La risposta è interessante, però a mio avviso "analisi dei dati" traduce meglio il termine "data analysis", che, per come lo percepisco io, è un campo diverso, ad esempio non studia l'attività di data mining, che invece è studiata dalla data science. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science. Prima di accettare vorrei aspettare e vedere se arriva qualche proposta più centrata.

Comment: Alla fine ho optato per analisi dati e analista dati; nel contesto in cui ho usato questi termini "data analysis" e "data science" sono praticamente sinonimi. Penso però che in contesti più specifici sia necessaria una traduzione più precisa.

Answer (score 4):

Senza nulla togliere alla buona risposta di @abarisone, considera anche la possibilità di non tradurre *data science* e *data scientist*. Soprattutto noi che lavoriamo nell'IT siamo abituati ad utilizzare il termine inglese. Nota che anche nel titolo dell'articolo citato da @abarisone hanno fatto questa scelta.

Comment: Non concordo con questo punto di vista (lavoro nell'IT e trovo fuori luogo il proliferare di inglesismi di ogni tipo, anche perché dal mio punto di vista rendono sempre settoriale la comunicazione, sempre meno comprensibile se non si è addentro alla tematica discussa). Penso però che il voto negativo sia fuori luogo: effettivamente in ambiti tecnici la scelta di non tradurre questo tipo di espressioni è una scelta possibile.

Comment: @LuciaBentivoglio Grazie, certamente la scelta va soppesata, io volevo solo suggerire che la possibilità esiste. Per quanto riguarda il voto negativo non c'è motivo di preoccuparsi, stackexchange funziona così ed è giusto che chi dissente lo esprima anche in questo modo

Comment: Lo so, volevo solo sottolineare che la tua non è una "non-risposta", ma un'opzione valida.

Comment: Nella mia azienda (italiana) è stato appena istituito il ruolo di _data scientist_, chiamato esattamente così.